# python, reducing memory consumption and making this code more efficient?

Tags: python, memory, mbox

I have written this code (It works - I tried it on small batch of MBOX file). However, when I try it on an MBOX file that has a size of 2.9 GB of about 50,000 mails, the memory consumption skyrocket, making the computer unusable. what is wrong with this code in term of memory consumption and is there is a way to fix it, such as making the code process by increments instead of a whole? 
**the goal** of this script, is to produce a CSV file with x as date and Y as the count of message received per that date, in order to plot them and produce a statistical representation of the Email. 
**for future:**  I am planning to expand this, to read the email messages and produce an output on a pdf chronologically, so it needs to be sorted (where the memory consumption skyrocket)

```
    import mailbox
    from email.utils import parsedate
    from dateutil.parser import parse
    import itertools
    import plotly.plotly as py
    from plotly.graph_objs import *
    import plotly.tools as tls
    import csv
    from itertools import izip

    path = 'mail.mbox'
    mbox = mailbox.mbox(path)

    def extract_date(email):
        date = email.get('Date')
        return parsedate(date)

 #sort the email by a given date
    sorted_mails = sorted(mbox, key=extract_date)
    mbox.update(enumerate(sorted_mails))
    mbox.flush()

 #it finds all the dates within the MBOX and split
    all_dates = []
    mbox = mailbox.mbox(path)
    for message in mbox:
        all_dates.append( str( parse( message['date'] ) ).split(' ')[0] )

 #counts the number of emails per given date
    email_count = [(g[0], len(list(g[1]))) for g in itertools.groupby(all_dates)]
    email_count[0]

 #makes a list of (x,y)
    x = []
    y = []
    for date, count in email_count:
        x.append(date)
        y.append(count)

 #produce a CSV file of X and Y, for plotting
    with open('data.csv', 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(izip(x, y))
   """
   data = Data([x, y])
   plot_url = py.iplot(Data, filename='line-scatter' )
  """
    py.iplot( Data([ Scatter( x=x, y=y ) ]) )
```

Comment: I'd suggest to debug the code and check the memory usage while excecuting the code line by line. Helping you would be easier if you could tell us want you are going to achieve.

Comment: If using external tools is acceptable, extracting just the dates with something like `formail -czxDate: -s <mbox` would reduce the amount of unnecessary I/O in subsequent processing steps quite significantly. A drawback is that this makes it harder to pinpoint e.g. messages with erroneous headers in any later stage of the pipeline.

Comment: @jochen ,  memory consumption happens around sorted_mails block. I am trying to produce CSV output with dates and the number of message/email receiver per that date. the sorting for convenience on CSV as later i am planning to expand the code to read the message and produce an output on a pdf chronologically.

Comment: @tripleee, i thought of that previously, but it won't help - since i am trying to make a statistical representation of the email and having the dates extracted by external tools of +50K will make the task tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with these libraries, but I think the main issue is that you're reading all the messages into memory with this line:

```
sorted_mails = sorted(mbox, key=extract_date)
```

What is the goal of this script? Do you really need to sort anything? If you just need to produce a CSV with counts per date, try this:

```
import mailbox
from email.utils import parsedate
from dateutil.parser import parse
import itertools
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import plotly.tools as tls
import csv
from itertools import izip

path = 'mail.mbox'
mbox = mailbox.mbox(path)

# map date to number of emails seen on that date
date_counts = {}

for message in mbox:
    date = str( parse( message['date'] ) ).split(' ')[0]
    try:
        date_counts[date] += 1
    except KeyError:
        date_counts[date] = 1

with open('data.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for date in date_counts:
        writer.writerow([date, date_counts[date]])
```

Comment: the goal is to produce a csv to plot the data statistically later, to have a visual representation of an email. but also have a plan to expand the code, to read the message and produce an output on a pdf in order of when received first. So i technically need it to be sorted for later use. but your code  actually works when i omit sorting.

Comment: You should do any sorting in a different script, because it's going to be expensive to sort a 2.9 GB file and it's not necessary to get counts.

Comment: I see your point! It makes sense to separate the sorting task from the script. while at it, how feasible do you think to produce a pdf of al 50k l emails after sorting?

Comment: I would question the usefulness of a PDF that contains 50K emails, but I guess it's possible. For the sorting step, you might want to look at [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) algorithms because they avoid loading everything into memory at the same time.

Comment: awesome! Thank you for your help and straightforwardness. cheers!